# Django App Engine: Filter and Order of a DateTimeField - Filter Not Working

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

I am running a query on Django on top of Google App Engine (using django-nonrel).  I am trying to determine all currently scheduled emails in my app.  I do this, by querying for all emails that should have already been sent and ordering by the scheduled time.

However, when I run the query, the filter is not being honored. Meaning, emails are returned that occur in the future. Why is the filter not working?

My model is:

```
class EmailContact(models.Model):
    email        = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    unsubscribed = models.BooleanField(default=False)       
    next_email   = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
```

And my query is:

```
ems = models.EmailContact.objects.filter(unsubscribed=False
        ).filter(next_email__lte = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        ).order_by("-next_email")
```

The result is that items are returned where the `next_email` property is greater than `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`. Am I doing something wrong? This query appears to work in the development environment, so I think there is something specific to GAE's datastore.

Comment: I's datetime.datetime.utcnow() returning the 'now' you desire or are there a few hour's of slip? Do `EmailContact.next_email` have proper values stored?

Comment: Yes and yes... not sure what's going on here.